# Network Set Modelling

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

**Problem**

Given the following circuit

[image]

If we consider each event $A_i=$"The component $i$ fails" in the transmission $(i=1,2...,9)$ Write the event $B$ = "The circuit fails" in terms of the events $A_1,A_2,...,A_9$

**What I thought**

I thought that maybe writing, how it would be written: (how the information would be transfer from the left to the right), and given that each $A_i$ means The component $i$ fails. In this way the event $B$  = "The circuit fails" could be written.

$B=\left\{\left(A_5\cap A_6\right)\cup \left(\left(\left(A_1\cup A_2\right)\cup \left(A_3\cap A_4\right)\right)\cap \left(\left(A_7\right)\cup \left(A_8\cap A_9\right)\right)\right)\right\}$

Reading that is basically reading that the components failed, in each possible way in which the current flows. But I'm not sure if that's enough to model the event $B$ or if did it properly